# Socket.io connection fails between client and server side (Reacr/Node.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to get a basic socket connection.

The server looks like this :

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const port = 4000;
    const server = require("http").createServer(app);
    let io = require("socket.io")(server);

    app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Server up"));

    io.on("connection", socket => {
      console.log("a user connected");
    });

    app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"));

    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

The React component looks like this :

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import io from "socket.io-client";

    const ChatScreen = () => {

      const socket = io('localhost:4000');


      useEffect(() => {
      }, []);

      return (
        <div className="chatScreen">HI</div>
      );
    };

    export default ChatScreen;
```

As I got from reading, I should be getting a console.log "a user connected" in the server. 
But I get these 2 errors :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N2xxl7i' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-
Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

And

```
polling-xhr.js:267 GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N2xy65_ 
net::ERR_FAILED
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In your node js app, you can try to add the following after `var app = express();` :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that your Express server doesn't allow any external request. Your React server is an external server, that's the reason of this error.

To fix this error, simply use the [cors middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) as:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors= require("cors");
const app = express();
const port = 4000;
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
let io = require("socket.io")(server);

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Server up"));

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("a user connected");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

**Documentation:** https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: Thank u. Did it and now it gives another error : 


Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N2y1e63' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds weird. Maybe try to have a look into cors' configuration, you should be able to fix that easily from there.